# "Up with the... " (complete the saying for waking up early)

Tags: early-modern-english

If you wake up early, what is the saying for this? Beginning with the words: "Up with the..."

Comment: Substitute any aspect of the early morning: up with the dawn, the birds, the sun, whatever.

Comment: Is it about rhymes..

Comment: Why is this question tagged as "early-modern-english"—because it's about describing in modern English someone who is awake early?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're thinking of "[be up with the lark](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+up+with+the+lark)".

If not larks, then you're probably thinking of "be up with the crows".

Larks and crows sing (or in a crow's case, squawk noisily) early in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

"Up with the sun, gone with the wind,
She always said I was lazy..."
   "Traveling Man", Bob Seger